# How to specify IIS Web Application Name in Parameters.xml used with MSDeploy

Tags: msdeploy

I have found out how to set the application pool and default value

```
<parameter name="applicationPool" defaultValue="MyDefaultValue" >
  <parameterEntry kind="DeploymentObjectAttribute" scope="application"
                  match="application/@applicationPool" />
</parameter>
```

Does anyone know how to set the "IIS Web Application Name"?  It gets generated in the SetParameters.xml file as

```
<setParameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="Default Web Site/MySite_deploy" />
```

I can overwrite the SetParameters.xml file, but I would rather set it up in the Parameters.xml file, but I can't find the parameterEntry type.

Thanks

Comment: I dont follow the question, can you explain what steps you are taking and what you would like to happen?

Comment: Basically I want to have a different web site than "Default Web Site", but I would prefer to specify this in the default value of the Parameters.xml file.  That way I will not need to overwrite the generated SetParameters.xml file.

Comment: So you're building a package that you are later publishing with msdeploy.exe?

Comment: Correct.  I currently overwrite the SetParameters.xml file before calling the msdeploy cmd file.  I would like to just store the default values in parameters.xml file so that I only have one file in each of my solutions.  I can set things like AppPool and physical path, but the one thing I apparently can't do is set the IIS web application.  Just trying to simplify our deploy process to remove a step.  Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should be able to override the default value stored in the package by defining a `DeployIisAppPath` property when you generate the package

Alternatively, you can declare `DisableAllVSGeneratedMSDeployParameter=true` and Visual Studio will no longer automatically generate *any* parameters for you, you'll have to declare them all yourself.

If you're declaring the web site parameter yourself, the *kind* will be `ProviderPath`. The scope will either be `iisApp` or `contentPath` depending on what provider is being used. Tear open a package and look in the `archive.xml` file, the value will be an immediate child of the root manifest element.

Comment: Thanks Richard, both approaches worked.

`--Project file  `<PropertyGroup<DisableAllVSGeneratedMSDeployParameter>true</DisableAllVSGeneratedMSDeployParameter></PropertyGroup>
`
`--Parameters.xml
`<parameter name="IIS Web Application Name"   defaultValue="MySite/MyApp">
      <parameterEntry kind="ProviderPath" scope="IisApp" match="@defaultValue" />
    </parameter>

or

`--project file
`<PropertyGroup>
`    <DeployIisAppPath>MySite/MyApp</DeployIisAppPath>
`  </PropertyGroup>

I went with the second approach.

Comment: Where do you put `<DisableAllVSGeneratedMSDeployParameter>True</DisableAllVSGeneratedMSDeployParameter>`?  In the Visual Studio project file?

Comment: @Heinrich Either in a `PropertyGroup` element or as a command line parameter `/p:DisableAllVSGeneratedMSDeployParameter=true`

Comment: @RichardSzalay If I use a `<PropertyGroup>` element, which **file** does it go in?  I've tried this in my `csproj` file and it just gives a compile error about `DisableAllVSGeneratedMSDeployParameter`.  I'm using `VS2013`.

Comment: @Heinrich - Your `.pubxml` would be your best choice, but you can also put it in your `csproj`. An XML file named `ProjectName.wpp.xml` would also be shared between all publish profiles.

Comment: I did not get the parameters.xml file to work but adding the DeployIisAppPath to the csproj file worked.