# Visual Studio Web Deploy Package and DisableAllVSGeneratedMSDeployParameter

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy

I'm trying to make the Web Deploy Package generated by Visual Studio 2013 ask for the MSDeploy packages at runtime.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220297/how-to-specify-iis-web-application-name-in-parameters-xml-used-with-msdeploy) article explains that you can do this by disabling the parameter generation.  It says to put `<DisableAllVSGeneratedMSDeployParameter>true</DisableAllVSGeneratedMSDeployParameter>` in the project file.  I've done this and it didn't work.  I get this error

```
Error 1 The command "DisableAllVSGeneratedMSDeployParameter" exited with code 9009. WebApplicationName
```

This is the section I added in the ASP.NET Web Project (Web API) csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DeployAsIisApp>False</DeployAsIisApp>
    <IncludeIisSettingsOnPublish>False</IncludeIisSettingsOnPublish>
    <IncludeSetAclProviderOnDestination>False</IncludeSetAclProviderOnDestination>
    <DisableAllVSGeneratedMSDeployParameter>True</DisableAllVSGeneratedMSDeployParameter>
</PropertyGroup>
```

[This](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2010/07/web-deploy-parameterization-in-action.html) article also says this can be done if you read down in the comments.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I found out it goes in the publish settings file `.pubxml` that is created in `Project Folder/Properties/PublishProfiles` when you create a profile in the Publish->Web Deploy Package dialog.  There wasn't an error after putting it there.

It didn't do what I wanted.  It didn't allow me to specify the physical IIS path just the acl settings.